# How to check for a running process with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, rufus-scheduler

I use a scheduler (Rufus scheduler) to launch a process called "ar_sendmail" (from ARmailer), every minute.

The process should NOT be launched when there is already such a process running in order not to eat up memory.

How do I check to see if this process is already running? What goes after the `unless` below?

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

  scheduler.every '1m' do

    unless #[what goes here?]
      fork { exec "ar_sendmail -o" }
      Process.wait
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
unless `ps aux | grep ar_sendmai[l]` != ""
```

Comment: Thanks! 1 question back: Why the brackets around the "l" of "ar_sendmail"?

Comment: it's to remove the calling process from the grep for a process that matches ar_sendmail - otherwise you'd get a result for 'grep ar_sendmail'

Comment: And if you want to extract the pids: `ps aux | grep ar_sendmai[l] | awk '{ print $2 }'`

Comment: Hi! @stef, what is the approach if  I'm using some Rails method (for example Email.send_notifications) instead of above process - fork { exec "ar_sendmail -o" } ?

Comment: Don't use `unless` with `!=` as it results in mental anguish. Instead use `if` and `==`: `if something == something_else` is more easily understood than `unless something != something_else`.

Comment: For simpler checks use `pidof ar_sendmail`.

Answer (score 8):

```
unless `pgrep -f ar_sendmail`.split("\n") != [Process.pid.to_s]
```

Comment: I think this is a much better solution as you  don't have to use the bracket thing to exclude the calling process.

Comment: EDIT: Needed the split on \n because of the return structure of pgrep.

Answer (score 1):

This looks neater I think, and uses built-in Ruby module. Send a 0 kill signal (i.e. don't kill):

```
  # Check if a process is running
  def running?(pid)
    Process.kill(0, pid)
    true
  rescue Errno::ESRCH
    false
  rescue Errno::EPERM
    true
  end
```

Slightly amended from [Quick dev tips](http://dev.housetrip.com/2014/03/24/ruby-pid-tip/)  You might not want to rescue EPERM, meaning "it's running, but you're not allowed to kill it".

Comment: it returns true, even if the process already in `defunct` state as reported by ps